# Encoding discrete and categorical data with one hot encoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset that involves both discrete and continuous data variables. For example: Gender, Occupation, Salary. Salary is a field that carries a lot of information to predict my class. Now I have the Gender and Occupation columns mapped by an One Hot Encoder. How do I map the salary values to the output array I get as a result of encoding.

In this problem I am trying to use a decision tree to classify data, hence I would like salary to retain it's value so that the decision tree would be able to predict the final class using normal numeric operators.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your code.